# Ways to do a dynamic query in node.js

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, node-mysql

I'm trying to figure out how to do dynamic queries in node.js with node-mysql. Which table and fields to insert and update is based on users' request from the `data` object. I thought of creating a module to store different queries like the following but no luck. It gave me this error:

```
TypeError: Object function (){
   var likes = 'INSERT IGNORE INTO item (id,like_type) VALUES(?,?)';
   return likes;
 } has no method 'replace'
```

app.js

```
 var queries = require('./queries');
 .....

 socket.on("like",function(data){ 
  var table_file = data[0].table;
  var d = data[1];  
  connection.query(queries[table_file]
    ,[d.id,d.like_type],function(err,rows,fields){ 
     if(err){ throw err;}
     console.log(rows);
    });
```

queries.js:

```
module.exports = {
 item_like:function(){
   var likes = 'INSERT IGNORE INTO item (id,like_type) VALUES(?,?)';
   return likes;
 },
 people:function(){
   var likes = 'INSERT IGNORE INTO people (id,like_type) VALUES(?,?)';
   return likes;
 }
}
```

Here's the data object sent to socket:

```
data object: {table:item_like},{id:1,like_type:1};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your exports in `queries.js` to be set to the SQL strings instead of functions, since that is how you're treating them currently:

```
module.exports = {
 item_like: 'INSERT IGNORE INTO item (id,like_type) VALUES(?,?)',
 people: 'INSERT IGNORE INTO people (id,like_type) VALUES(?,?)'
}
```